# Using multiple sites in virtual hosts (apache)

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have installed XAMPP on my windows box - I am trying to run multiple websites in the virtual hosts file but no matter I seem to do I can only run one site at a time. e.g to run site three i need to comment out all references to site 1 & 2 (and vice-versa).

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

My v/hosts file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName s1.localhost
ServerAlias s1.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site1/public_html"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/site1/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
   Options FollowSymlinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName s2.localhost
ServerAlias s2.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site2/public_html"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/site2/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName s3.localhost
ServerAlias s3.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site3"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/site3">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My Windows Host file:

```
127.0.0.1 s1.localhost
127.0.0.1 s2.localhost
127.0.0.1 s3.localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NameVirtualHost *:80 - this line needs to be uncommented to fix this problem